# View with Page display won't show menu tab for an alias

Tags: views, path-aliases, routes

I want to add a few views (members and challenges) to a specific content type called group. I don't want the views to display all on the same page, this is easily done with the block display type. But I want to have menu tabs at the page, this is also easily done (`/node/%/members`) if you only use one content type. But I'm using multiple content types what than also will have the Members tab.

Basically I'm asking how to manage the visibility of a menu tab.

---

This is what I tried so far for the view Group Members (User):

```
Path: /group/%/members
Menu: Tab: Members
```

nothing showed up..

---

This is what I tried so far for the view Group specific Challenges (Content):

```
Path: /node/%/challenges
Menu: Tab: Challenges
```

It showed up on every node.

Comment: How about adding the views without menus, and then using Page Manager, override the node page and create variants. NodeOne has an excellent video series on Page Manager. [Learn Page manager!](http://nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your views as follows:

**Challenges -**

path: node/%/challenges

tab: menu tab with title Challenges

filter criteria: type = group

Contextual filter: nid, and in section WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED specify validation criteria: Validator Content, Content types group

**Members-**

path: node/%/members

tab: menu tab with title Members

filter criteria: you con't need any as you are displaying users (you have a view of users)

relationship: add a relationship to the node table such as: User: Content authored. This will bring in the related nodes.

Contextual filter: nid, in the section rlationships nodes must be selected. Specify validation criteria as Validator Content, Content types group

And these two tabs will now show up only for node type group. If you need it on other content types as well then adjust your views filter criteria and contextual filter validation as required.

Comment: Thank you this works great, I didn't know about this trick with contextual filters. This is my setup now:

Both views use this setting in their contextual filter:
`When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided, Specify validation criteria: Content - Group`

**Challenges**
`Path: /node/%/challenges; Filter criteria: Content: Type (= Group); Contextual filters: Content: Nid; Relationships: Content: Available challenge(s); Fields: "all relate to field_available"`
**Members**
`Path: /node/%/members; Contextual filters: User: Group`